# Why does this SQL code give error 1066 (Not unique table/alias: 'customer')?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, mysql-error-1066

Why does the MySQL query below give error `1066 (Not unique table/alias: 'customer')`?

```
SELECT customer.id, customer.firstName, account.id
FROM customer, account
INNER JOIN customer
ON customer.id = account.customerId 
ORDER BY customer.id
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have listed the table `customer` **twice** in your `FROM` statement. Here's the fixed version:

```
SELECT customer.id, customer.firstName, account.id
FROM account
INNER JOIN customer
ON customer.id = account.customerId
ORDER BY customer.id
```

Comment: @Mark: That sure was a close one, though :)